# firebase_ml_vision breaks IOS build, fix for Windows machine

Tags: ios, windows, firebase, flutter, firebase-mlkit

I have a windows machine and would like to build my flutter app for my Iphone. I am using codemagic.com to build my app. With the firebase_ml_vision dependency there is an error when building the app for iOS as seen here, https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28625. I am not sure how to fix this on my windows machine because i am unable to access the iOS build files.

Here is the error message when building the app for iOS

Returning local
    [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "firebase_ml_vision":
      In Podfile:
        firebase_ml_vision (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_ml_vision/ios`)

```
Specs satisfying the `firebase_ml_vision (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_ml_vision/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

Comment: Can you share your Podfile?  Please make sure you have "platform :ios, '9.0'" at the top of your Podfile. Also please update to the latest version of Firebase ML: deleting your Pods directory, remove the Podfile.lock file, run "pod cache clean --all" and then run "pod update".  The latest GoogleAppMeasurement 6.5.0 should be used.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using firebase_ml_vision: ^0.10.0 or up, you have to change your Deployment target to 10.0:

In your Podfile: `platform :ios, '10.0'`

In your Xcode project set `iOS Deployment Target` to 10.0

Then, run the following in your terminal to build with a fresh state:

```
flutter clean \
    && rm ios/Podfile.lock pubspec.lock \
    && rm -rf ios/Pods ios/Runner.xcworkspace \
    && flutter build iOS
```